# Where was Sword Art Online published online?

Tags: sword-art-online

I heard SAO was published online before being published in paper (not sure if only the first volume or more). Now, the question is where was it published, which site?

I understand that the webnovel version of SAO is likely no longer available there. I'm more interested in the site. I tried googling it but I've got no answer, so I'm asking it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to (legally) find the web novel version anymore as the author has pulled it out after agreeing to publish it with ASCII Media Works. As for the website it was published in, it would be on SAO's author Reki Kawahara's [website.](http://wordgear.x0.com/novel/)

Keep in mind that he used the pseudonym "Fumio Kunori" when he was writing this particular web novel series.

Source:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online#Light_novels

Comment: I missed the annotation with the link to the author's site (it was next to the part mentioning the webnovel), when I checked the article before. Thanks for your help. Originally I was wondering if the novel was posted on an web novel aggregate site or somewhere else.